# FrameworkElement.BringToFront() and SendToBack() implementations

Tags: c#, wpf

I was looking for what I hoped would be trivial, but apparently it isn't, because I could find anything satisfying online: an implementation of `FrameworkElement.BringToFront()` and `FrameworkElement.SendToBack()`.

My scenario was that I had several custom controls that were renderer within a `Canvas` by a `ContentPresenter`. I can debug the visual trees of both controls like this:

```
Element1:                                    
    CustomControl {HashCode: 35948007}      
    ContentPresenter {HashCode: 52397778}      
    Canvas {HashCode: 47345023}                
    ItemsPresenter {HashCode: 23452031}        
    Border {HashCode:  5260558}                
    ItemsControl {HashCode: 34643909}          
    ...

Element2:
    CustomControl {HashCode:  9741694}
    ContentPresenter {HashCode:  3532547}
    Canvas {HashCode: 47345023}          
    ItemsPresenter {HashCode: 23452031}  
    Border {HashCode:  5260558}          
    ItemsControl {HashCode: 34643909}    
    ...
```

As you can see, their common ancestor is "Canvas {HashCode: 47345023}". And setting the Z-Index of the custom controls didn't help, because Z-Index is always relative to the siblings, which they don't have. I ended up with the following, which walks up the visual tree to find the first `Panel` and the ancestor of my custom control that is a child of that panel so I can set the Z-Index of that ancestor.

```
public static void BringToFront(this FrameworkElement element)
{
    setZIndex(element, indices => indices.Max() + 1);
}

public static void SendToBack(this FrameworkElement element)
{
    setZIndex(element, indices => indices.Min() - 1);
}

private static void setZIndex(this FrameworkElement element, Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> indexCallback)
{
    DependencyObject ancestor = element;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

    while (parent != null && !(parent is Panel))
    {
        ancestor = parent;
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    if (parent is Panel panel && ancestor is UIElement ancestorElement)
    {
        var index = indexCallback(panel.ChildrenOfType<UIElement>().Select(e => Panel.GetZIndex(e)));
        Panel.SetZIndex(ancestorElement, index);
    }
}
```

Question: Is this a good approach? It appears so complicated...

Comment: This shouldn't be "simple" static methods. Both depend on an instance of `Canvas`. It would be more elegant to extend `Canvas` or create an attached behavior that targets `Panel` or modify your methods to take the hosting `Panel` as argument or turn the methods into extension methods of `Panel`. This way you have always direct access to the hosting `Panel` and therefore to all siblings of the target element. You would only have to set `Panel.ZIndex` without the need to search  the visual tree for a parent `Panel`. This will reduce lines of  code.

Comment: @BionicCode But exactly that is part of my problem: the controls are children rendered as part of a `DataTemplate` - they don't know (and shouldn't explicitly have to know) which panel they are ultimately rendered in.

Comment: I also think that the items don't have to know their `Panel`, this wasn't on my mind. I assume there is some object that knows which child belongs to which `Panel`. The same object that is responsible to change the z index of these children. If you don't have access to the hosting `Panel` then searching it is the only solution. You didn't provide any information on how you are using your methods. I don't have enough information to really help or  improve. I just provided an alternative solution that doesn't need visual tree traversal.